# Calling .Net Classes from Visual Basic 6

Tags: .net, vb6, methods, com-interop

I have a .net dll file. I have to call one of the methods in this dll file from a VB program.

This dll file uses another .net dll file for logging purpose.

I able to call a .net class library method from VB6 application. But, I am getting the exception that unable to load assembly (which is used for logging).

How the vb6 application will search the dll files required for the execution?

Comment: when deploying are you ready to install the .NET framework on the target machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VB6 can only work with .NET if the .NET classes are exposed as COM objects. And unless the .NET programmers knew you needed to call their method, chances are they didn't expose their classes as COM objects.

Answer (score 1):

Are both .NET assemblies in the GAC?  You should be using the following -

Type Library Exporter (Tlbexp.exe)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c.aspx

... and/or Assembly Registration Tool (Regasm.exe)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using com-call to make sure you can acces functionality out of your .net project it will indeed search through your .dll file. If you are trying to do things that depend on the logging and you have not compiled it with the dll used in your comcall it won't be able to run because of dependencies.